# Public_activity gem with a profile model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, public-activity

Im using the [public_activity gem](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity/blob/1-5-stable/README.md#common-examples). I have a post model, user model (generated with devise) and a profile model.

Using the public_activity gem I can get the news feed to show when a `Post` is created, edited or deleted, but i need a way to show the users name associated with the `Post`, the user name is stored in the `Profile` model and not the `User` model generated by `devise`. Here is what I have so far:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_one :profile
end
```

post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: Proc.new{ |controller, model| controller.current_user }
end
```

Profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have the standard views set up for example `views/public_activity/post/_create.html.erb`

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <% if a.trackable %>
    <%= a.trackable.name %> was created.
  <% else %>
    An article that is currently deleted was added.
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Im trying something like this to:

```
<div class="activities">
  <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <div class="activity">
    <%= activity.owner.profile.name %>
    <%= render_activities(@activities) %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

but this is not working, error is:

```
undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass
```